# Android Fragment showing fragment as null even if it is not null

Tags: android, android-fragments

```
 public void onBackPressed() {
    getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment2);
    if(null != (webfragment) && (webfragment) instanceof BackListner) {
        ((BackListner) webfragment).goBack();
    }

    else {
        super.onBackPressed();
        finish();

    }
}
```

Where 
Webfragment webframgent;
and Webfragment is a different class which is extending fragment and implementing BackListner
and BackListner is a custom Listner

and in goBack() I have

```
 public void goBack() {
    if(webview.canGoBack()){
        webview.goBack();
    }
    else{
        webview.removeAllViews();
        webview.clearHistory();
        webview.clearCache(true);
        webview.loadUrl("about:blank");
        webview.freeMemory();
        webview.pauseTimers();

        webview.destroy();
        onDetach();
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Cannot Go Back",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Please Help
Thanks in advance :)

Comment: can you post the entire code

Comment: I'm supposing that your fragment2 is the id to a XML fragment?

Comment: Yes its the framelayout in the mainactivity where the fragment loads the webview